# Create a pptp tunnel through a exisiting domain

Tags: domain, pptp, tunneling, pptpd

I want to create a tunnel (preferably pptp) via a website that I created

I am renting a domain from an ISP with a linux os,

is it possible to create it?

Answer (score 1):

No. You need have root to the server end of the tunnel to do this. It's not just as simple as "turning it on" - there's a lot of configuration that needs doing that you need administrative rights to do.

Comment: okay, if I am able to get root access, what would the basic steps be to follow, btw thnx for your answer

Comment: I'm not going to give you the "basic steps" because there is no such thing. This is a site for professionals and you need to have at least a basic understanding of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: in all respect, i believe this site is made of professionals to help "less" professional people trying to learn, not break them down for trying to achieve something, (btw, I am doing a computer science degree at univeristy with netowrking modules), so for future sake, dont judge and assume others dont know anything!

Comment: Correct, I'm afraid the demonstrated knowledge in this question does not register on the "professional" scale however. I hate sounding overly preachy but it's good life advice: Nobody cares how much you know, or how much you claim to know, or should know; they only care how much you can demonstrate that knowledge. Get root access, find a guide to setting up a PPTP tunnel, try it; if that doesn't go well come back with the specific problem you're facing; we'll be glad to help - even Mark.